# Trying to learn recursive functions, but can't wrap my head round it

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to learn how to use recursive functions, but am not understanding what is happening at all.

```
function power(base, exponent) {
    return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
};

alert(power(4,4));
```

I'm getting:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

From the example that I'm going off of, it has:

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}

alert(power(4,4));
```

Could someone explain to me why the if statement is needed? I suspect that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A recursive function calls itself. That's the definition of it.

This brings a problem: it will indefinitely call itself. So it will go forever which is why you're getting stack overflows.

Instead, you should stop at a certain point. This is where the `if` clause comes in. When `exponent == 0`, you don't call the function, but stop the process.

So when executing `power(3, 3)` it will go like:

```
   power(3, 3) is equal to:

   3 * power(3, 2)
or 3 * 3 * power(3, 1)
or 3 * 3 * 3 * power(3, 0)
or 3 * 3 * 3 * 1            // no additional calls anymore; can be calculated now
```

---

Seen from a little different angle:

- `power(4, 4)` is defined as  `4 * power(4, 3)` by the function.
- `power(4, 3)` is defined as  `4 * power(4, 2)` by the function.
- `power(4, 2)` is defined as  `4 * power(4, 1)` by the function.
- `power(4, 1)` is defined as  `4 * power(4, 0)` by the function.
- `power(4, 0)` is defined as  `1` by the function.

If you substitute everything into each previous one, you'll obtain:

```
                         power(4, 4)
equals               4 * power(4, 3)
equals           4 * 4 * power(4, 2)
equals       4 * 4 * 4 * power(4, 1)
equals   4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * power(4, 0)
equals   4 * 4 * 4 * 4 *      1   
equals   256
```

Comment: Ah I understand now. Are there any benefits to using recursion instead of a loop? I'm guessing loops would be cheaper.

Comment: Actually there's one more thing that I don't understand yet. I don't get why the first part of the if statement has to return 1. Why can't I just use break?

Comment: @Dan: Well, recursion may be a more elegant approach. It probably is more expensive, but your example shows a compact and nice use of recursion. As for `break`, that keyword means something different. It's to break out of loops, not functions. If you look at the penultimate line of my example you see that `power(3, 0)` has to return `1` (there you have it, `return`).

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I understand the part where if exponent == 1, it returns 1 and doesn't run the body of the function again. Why then, doesn't it return 1 when I alert power(4,4) and instead 4*4*4*4? 


edit: While messing around with the function, I noticed if I change the first part of the if statement to: if(exponent == 0) return 2, it doubles it. I guess I'm not understanding return, or the function completely. I'm getting there though.

Comment: @Dan: It's doing `4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 1`. If you change that `1` to `2`, you can see that it will do `* 2`, i.e. doubling the result.

Comment: @Dan: Perhaps alerting the values in between helps: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/YhcFr/.

Comment: Thanks, you've been a big help so far. I've been playing around with that chunk of code, and I understand most of what is happening. The one problem that I still don't get, is why it multiplies by 1. I thought if you, for example say return 1, you're setting the function to equal 1. 

By writing this out, I think I may have just understood it. When exponent == 1, you're still multiplying base by the function power and subtracting 1 from exponent, making it 0. It still has to go though the body of power, so It goes to the first part of the if statement and multiplies by 1.Is that right?

Comment: @Dan: Yes I think you got it. Perhaps my edit also helps a little. You just have to get it, then it's rather easy in fact :)

Comment: Your edit makes everything more clear to me. Hopefully it makes sense to others with the same question. Thanks!

Comment: @pimvdb Thank you for writing out in code what the recursion equates to; it helps clarify how the computation is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5):

You need a base case in recursion so that it stops calling itself. In this case, the power function is called forever (well, until the javascript interpreter gives up) as the exponent goes to negative infinity.

Answer (score 3):

A recursive function calls itself. So you need some mechanism to tell it to stop or you will be in an infinite loop. In your case you always return and provide no means for exiting the loop. Hence the RangeError.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the function is calling itself. In your first example, the function calls itself, and then the newly called function calls itself and so on. Internally, your computer is storing these function calls in a memory structure called a stack. When there is no more memory for storing function calls, you have exceeded the call stack size.

In the second example, you have a way of escaping this vicious circle. The base case lets the function return, and so you "pop" the method calls off the stack.

Note that in your second example, you can start with alert(power(4, -1)) and you will again experience the same problem, because now your function will subtract one from -1, giving you -2, and so on. You could fortify the code by using

```
if (exponent <= 0 )
```

... instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give it some corner conditions because otherwise it will keep calling itself over and over. Because stack size is limited, it will reach end of stack memory, and then an error will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is actually calling function within its own function body again & again until you get your desired result.

```
public int FactorialOfNumber(int k) {

    if (k==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return k * FactorialOfNumber(k-1);  //Function called within Function.
}
```

What happens that Recursion uses stack to operate?

Suppose if k=1, returns 1.

If k=4, control goes to else, returns (4*FactorialOfNumber(3)). since you doesn't know , FactorialOfNumber(3). it stores at top of stack.

now, k=3, control goes to else, it returns (3*FactorialOfNumber(2)). nw this goes to top of stack.

now k=2, returns (2*FactorialOfNumber(1)), top of stack.

Finally it calls i.e pops from stack, finally (4*FactorialOfNumber(3)) is called.

If a recursive method never reaches a base case, The stack will never stop growing. The computer, however, limits the stack to a particular height, so that no program eats up too much memory. If a program's stack exceeds this size, the computer initiates an exception, which typically would crash the program. The exception is labeled a StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 1):

The if creates a check to stop the recursion when the exponent reaches zero. Without it, it will continue with negative values and never stops.